# MySQL index: what's the difference between how 2 fields are indexed?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

There are 2 fields that I rely on for searching through the table: field1, field2. They are not unique through all the records, neither individually nor combined.

So I'm adding indexes for them:

Approach one:

```
alter table xx add index (field1, field2);
alter table xx add index (field2);
```

Approach two:

```
alter table xx add index (field1);
alter table xx add index (field2);
```

My question is what are the differences between these 2 approaches if any? For each of the following select queries:

```
select * from table xx where field1 = ??
select * from table xx where field2 = ??
select * from table xx where field1 = ?? and field2 = ??
select * from table xx where field1 = ?? or field2 = ??
```

Which approach is better?

And, which approach is the better one for this query?

```
select * from table xx where field1 = ?? and field2 = ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the queries you've posted approach 1 will be better, since composite index `(field1, field2)` will be used for queries with `field1 = ?? and field2 = ??`

As of `field1 = ?? or field2 = ??` query - [index merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-optimization.html) will be tried to apply, and doesn't matter which approach to choose for this kind query.

To summarize: if you have `field1 = ?? and field2 = ??` - then composite index is what you have to choose.